# Swipe event overriding touch events on ipad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, input

I have got a contact form with few inputs, but seems like the following code is overriding the touch event, so the submit button (or any element where the user have to touch, also the input text to type some question) does not work.

```
$.fn.swipeEvents = function() {
      return this.each(function() {

        var startX,
            startY,
            $this = $(this);

        $this.bind('touchstart', touchstart);

        function touchstart(event) {
          var touches = event.originalEvent.touches;
          if (touches && touches.length) {
            startX = touches[0].pageX;
            startY = touches[0].pageY;
            $this.bind('touchmove', touchmove);
          }
          event.preventDefault();
        }

        function touchmove(event) {
          var touches = event.originalEvent.touches;
          if (touches && touches.length) {
            var deltaX = startX - touches[0].pageX;
            var deltaY = startY - touches[0].pageY;

            if (deltaX >= 50) {
              $this.trigger("swipeLeft");
            }
            if (deltaX <= -50) {
              $this.trigger("swipeRight");
            }
            if (deltaY >= 50) {
              $this.trigger("swipeUp");
            }
            if (deltaY <= -50) {
              $this.trigger("swipeDown");
            }
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) >= 50 || Math.abs(deltaY) >= 50) {
              $this.unbind('touchmove', touchmove);
            }
          }
          event.preventDefault();
        }

      });
    };
```

Deleting the following code, the user can use the touch event on inputs, so I suposed it is the problem, but it breaks the "One Page Scroll" function.

EDIT:

I found a solution, but could someone explain me if I am doing it right or not?

I just deleted `event.preventDefault();`

What does `event.preventDefault();` exactly?

(testing around I found out it was the problem), but I am not sure about if that event is useless or in the other hand I just broke the script.

In the other hand, it works on Ipad & Screen Browser.